# JavaScript - Flexible arguments

Tags: javascript, object, error-handling, arguments

I'm trying to create a small structure in JavaScript that i will use inside a library for the canvas. I would like the arguments passed when creating this structure to be either multiple arguments like we do in compiled languages, OR an object with properties corresponding to these parameters :

```
BoundingBox = function( x, y, w, h ) {

    if( 'object' === typeof x ) {

        if( ! 'x' in x ) throw new Error('Property "x" missing');
        if( ! 'y' in x ) throw new Error('Property "y" missing');
        if( ! 'w' in x ) throw new Error('Property "w" missing');
        if( ! 'h' in x ) throw new Error('Property "h" missing');

        this.x = x.x;
        this.y = x.y;
        this.w = x.w;
        this.h = x.h;

    } else {

        if( null == x ) throw new Error('Parameter 1 is missing');
        if( null == y ) throw new Error('Parameter 2 is missing');
        if( null == w ) throw new Error('Parameter 3 is missing');
        if( null == h ) throw new Error('Parameter 4 is missing');

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
    }
};
```

and then :

```
var bb1 = new BoundingBox(0, 0, 200, 100);

var bb2 = new BoundingBox({
    x: 0,
    y: 0,
    w: 200,
    h: 100
});

var bb3 = new BoundingBox(bb2);
```

Is this a clean way to do it ? In the case we are using an object, using "x" as the object seems really weird.

And I have a second question :
Is all that error checking stuff worth the effort ? It doubles the size of the code, make it longer to read and write, and does not totally protect from having null or undefined values since properties are public.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You could create a simple `overload` function, with a signature such as `(func, types, newFunc)`, where `types` is an array of `typeof` values of the newly declared function. You can then seperate the overload logic and the different functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure to understand what you have in mind.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that's terrible but in JavaScript, overloading is accomplished more generically through the arguments var available to every function.

```
function BoundingBox(){

//do named functions with constructors. It sets the constructor.name
//property in instances, which can be handy sometimes

    if(typeof arguments[0] === 'object'){
        var coordsObj = arguments[0];
    }
    else {
        coordsObj = {} //no need for var dec even when upper if doesn't evaluate
        coordsObj.x = arguments[0];
        coordsObj.y = argumetns[1];
        //...etc.
    }
    //laziest way to make those publicly available.
    this.constructor.prototype = coordsObj;
}
```

As far as testing your params, I would say relax. Either wrap it in a try/catch that reports there's a problem with a params or learn to trust data in functions that don't rely on external sources. The whole dynamic typing thing is a lot less scary when you learn to be aware of the flow of data through your apps and you learn all the dynamic casting rules well enough to understand what's happening when something goes wrong, which isn't very often if your conscientious, which you should be even in strictly typed paradigms

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! What do you mean exactly by "no need for var dec even when upper if doesn't evaluate" ?

Comment: Also if i have methods in my object, using `this.constructor.prototype = coordsObj;` will remove that method won't it ?

Comment: The var counts as declared even if the if condition isn't true so you don't need to declare twice in an if/else. Prototypes act like a backup object to check if a method doesn't exist on your instance so they don't actually overwrite anything on the instance. That's why you can add a method to a constructor prototype and instances you've already created get access to the method too.

Answer (score 0):

My idea on the `overload` function is as follows: You can create a function `overload` that accepts a function, and a new function with its signature (as an array of `typeof` values). The returned function, then, checks whether the current call matches this signature and calls the new function in that case. Otherwise it calls the old function.

This way, you can overload a function by patching it a number of times. The definitions of the different functions and the actual overloading logic can be seperated this way. See http://jsfiddle.net/m2cRK/.

```
​var overload = function(oldFunc, types, newFunc) {
    return function() {
        var suffice = Array.prototype.every.call(arguments, function(v, i) {
            return typeof v === types[i];
        });
        return (suffice ? newFunc : oldFunc).apply(this, arguments);
    };
};
```

Usage (here's a function that doesn't require reassigning: http://jsfiddle.net/m2cRK/1/):

```
// The end of the chain, e.g. a function that throws a "no overload" error
var foo = overloadStart();

// Function 1
foo = overload(foo, ["number", "number"], function(a, b) {
    return a + b;
});

// Function 2
foo = overload(foo, ["object"], function(obj) {
    return obj.a + obj.b;
});


foo(1, 2);            // 3
foo({ a: 1, b: 2 });  // 3
foo("bar");           // error
```